# mongodb + java giving 'ok' should never be null , when DB name is injected via spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Mongodb version             - mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.8
mongodb java driver version - mongo-java-driver-2.12.0

Code

```
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB(getDbName());
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(getCollectionName());
    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
    dbObject.put("name","John Doe");
    collection.save(dbObject);
    mongoClient.close();
```

Stacktrace

> Jan 05, 2014 7:26:50 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError WARNING:
>   emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'ok' should never be null...  at
>   com.mongodb.CommandResult.ok(CommandResult.java:43)   at
>   com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:109)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._checkWriteError(DBTCPConnector.java:102)
>     at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:142)  at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:115)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:248)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)   at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:148)    at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:91)     at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:810)  at
>   com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:786)

Mongod console gives the below trace

> Sun Jan 05 19:38:08.289 [initandlisten] connection accepted from
>   127.0.0.1:50112  #5 (1 connection now open) Sun Jan 05 19:38:08.300 [conn5] assertion 16256 Invalid ns [
>
> ```
>                                     tinyblogdb
>
>                     .$cmd] ns:
>
>                                     tinyblogdb
>
>                     .$cmd query:{ getlasterror: 1 } Sun Jan 05 19:38:08.300 [conn5]       ntoskip:0 ntoreturn:-1 Sun Jan 05 19:38:08.300
> ```
>
> [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:50112 (0 connections no w open)

Any idea why this happens ?

**UPDATE**

If I hardcode the db name to the variable 'dbn' , the data gets inserted successfully , what I tried before was setter injection with spring in the method **getDbName()** , the below code works ! Now I am super curious why it doesn't work , when I inject the dbName ?

```
    String dbn = "tinyblogdb";
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbn);
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(getCollectionName());
    BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
    dbObject.put("name","John Doe");
    collection.save(dbObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason why it wasn't working while doing setter injection , here is the snippet of the spring injection.Even though I put the value in CDATA section , the white spaces were present and the space were also read as the part of the string.Trimming the string solved it.silly me.

```
    <![CDATA[ 

    tinyblogdb

                ]]>

    </value>
</property>
```

Comment: I was wondering about that looking at your debug output above.  That CDATA section isn't necessary, fwiw.

Comment: @evanchooly that was a handful of whitespace ! , I didn't notice it either. Only after a coffee break.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that getDbName() is returning something valid.  If it's an injected value you're almost certainly not getting injected properly and are passing in null.

Comment: this is what i am injecting , <![CDATA[ 

    tinyblogdb

                ]]>

And I found that white space is coming.So I had to trim it.